# How to install TikZ and PGF on OzTex 6?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to install the TikZ and PGF Packages on OzTex 6. so to be able do draw complex trees. Once downloaded I put them respectively in

```
OzTex-6/Tex/Inputs/LaTex/tikz-qtree
```

and

```
OzTex-6/Tex/Inputs/LaTex/pgf_3.
```

When I try to run a latex file with

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
```

OzTex states

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tikz.sty' not found.

! LaTeX Error: File `pgf.sty' not found.

! LaTeX Error: File `pgffor.sty' not found.
```

Am I misplacing something with pgf_3 ?

(pgf_3 contains `tikz.sty` at `pgf_3/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty` but seems unable to read it, the same for `pgf.sty` at 
`pgf_3/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty`, and `pgf_3/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty` )

( Or better I change from OzTex to Mactex ? My system is Mac Os 10.6.8 ?)

Comment: Switch to MacTeX.

Comment: ["OzTeX still works un­der Mac OS/X, but it is no longer be­ing main­tained or up­dated. Users in need of the lat­est and great­est are rec­om­mended to con­sider MacTeX."](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/oztex)

Comment: @MikeRenfro Do you mind converting that quote to an answer?

Answer (score 3):

From OzTeX's [CTAN page](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/oztex):

> "OzTeX still works un­der Mac OS/X, but it is no longer be­ing main­tained or up­dated. Users in need of the lat­est and great­est are rec­om­mended to con­sider MacTeX."

OzTeX 6.0 was released in 2008.

Comment: A remarkable piece of software. RIP. `;-)`

Comment: I used OzTex since 1993 till about 2010, after some time of inactivity I started to code again, but I could not reproduce trees with last version OzTeX 6.0. Thanks to your answers now I use MacTex and am able to use both TikZ and PGF,  for trees and other pictures. Thank you